# stacked area chart in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, stacked-area-chart

I want to create stacked area chart with d3js.
But the only example I am able to find on d3 site is this `http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211

I am not able to understand How I can plot date vs sales from this graph.
Sales on yaxis and date on xAxis.

If any body have some other example please point it to me 
thanks

Comment: If you want to chart absolute numbers rather than percentages, you should use something like this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3020685

Comment: What do you mean "sales"? Can you give us an example of what your data looks like?